# Troubles using FFmpegPCMAudio from discord

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
  info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
  await ctx.send('Сейчас играет: ' + info.get('title'))
  url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
  print(url2)
  source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, executable='/Users/someUser/ffmpeg', **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
  vc.play(source)
```

This works just fine, but the problem is that I am using a local ffmpeg.exe
It is okay if I start the app locally, **but my goal is to upload the project to GitHub and deploy it to Heroku, so I won't be able to reach the local file.** Maybe there is a better solution, **but I am only thinking of uploading the .exe to my GitHub repository, which is not that good...***
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Heroku may run Linux and `.exe` will be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add few build packs to your project in Heroku. Go to Application Settings and add the following buildpacks:[image: all buildpacks]

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Actually that's okay. I successfully found them, but I am having another problem.

Comment: @Ratery thank you so much!

Comment: Then, could you accept my answer, please? (Use a green tixk near it)

Comment: Of course! I suppose that another one is coming very soon...